# Connect to Informix via C#

Tags: c#, informix

I need to connect to Informix but what seemed to be an easy task is turning to be a bit annoying.
I downloaded the Client SDK and added the reference to the DLL.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IBM.Data.Informix;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {

        public static IfxConnection conn { get; set; }

        public static IfxCommand cmd { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a database connection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="host">Set the host of the database. Ex: 192.168.0.1</param>
        /// <param name="service">Set the service number (port). Ex: 1525</param>
        /// <param name="server">Set the server name. Ex: srv</param>
        /// <param name="database">Set the database name. Ex: InformixDB</param>
        /// <param name="userID">Set the userID. Ex: informix</param>
        /// <param name="password">Set the password. Ex: P@ssw0rd</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static void OpenConnection(string host, string service, string server, string database, string userID, string password)
        {
            string ConnectionString =
                "Host = " + host + "; " +
                "Service=" + service + "; " +
                "Server=" + server + "; " +
                "Database=" + database + "; " +
                "User Id=" + userID + "; " +
                "Password=" + password + "; ";

            try
            {
                conn = new IfxConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var ex = new Exception(string.Format("{0} - {1}", e.Message, (e as Win32Exception).ErrorCode));
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenConnection("", "", "", "", "", "");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I know I don't have any arguments on the OpenConnection method. And it isn't important in this case because it throws the exception even before atempting a connecting. It throws the exception when creating the IfxConnection object. It says "Unable to load DLL 'iclit09b.dll'".

According to [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21645914), the probable cause is that INFORMIXDIR and PATH have to be set as environment variables. But they're not really clear to to what exactly has to be set...

A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: INFORMIXDIR needs to be to the directory where you installed CSDK. PATH needs to be set to %INFORMIXDIR%\bin (basically, the directory containing the iclit09b.dll library.   In addition to that, when compiling, you have to use either x64 or x86. You can't use AnyCPU as the .NET driver is not fully managed and needs to load the natives libraries.

Comment: The suffix on the CSDK version (e.g. '4.10.FC11' or '4.10.TC11') will tell you what architecture the libraries are. 'F' is for the 64-bit CSDK, 'T' for the 32-bits

Comment: Hey, thanks. Now the only error is just the connection, which is perfectly normal as I don't yet have anything defined.
Though, the "%INFORMIXDIR%\bin" didn't work. I had to define the path like: Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("INFORMIXDIR")+ @"\bin");

Comment: Isn't there any way to get the informix directory in a dynamic way instead of specifying the whole path? The thing is, I'm testing the on a local machine but it will later be on a server, so it'll have to be redifined.

Comment: Also, as it'll be on a Linux server, do I have to specify anything else? I think not, as it just needs a DLL, but...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173827/discussion-between-j-s-and-taiko).

Comment: @J_S, put that into an answer, since it solved the issue, so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This old technote provides a simple guide of how to configure a Windows clients (including the required values for PATH and INFORMIXDIR environment variables)

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21083599